# make[1]: Entering directory error message

Tags: java, makefile

I have a simple Makefile:

```
default:
    @make build
    @make run

build:
    @javac Test.java > /dev/null

run:
    @java Test
```

During compilation, make outputs:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `<current directory'>
...
make[1]: Leaving directory `<current directory'>
```

I need make to build without printing these messages. Does anybody know what the problem or how to suppress these messages?

Thanks

---

edit: this happens regardless of the code. e.g. it happens with:

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("HELLO WORLD");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your code? We can't guess....

Comment: Any reason why compile Java with make? (I'm guessing "because the instructor said so" though.)

Comment: @Neal sorry, edited to include code snippet.  and Inerdial, we use make because the choice of language is up to us. The instructors just need a unified way of invoking all of our diverse programs.

Comment: That is not a valid makefile. By all means reduce the makefile to the simplest one that reproduces the behavior, but please don't post a fragment. If you show us the whole makefile we can tell you where to put the `@` and `-s`.

Comment: @Beta edited to include valid Makefile. I notice that if I don't nest the targets (i.e. just compile and run in default without the separate targets), it doesn't output those messages. However, I want to retain separate targets. Any ideas?

Comment: In case it helps anyone, I wanted to be sure that those messages **were ** output & discovered the `--print-directory` option to make, e.g. `make all --print-directory`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Change `make` to `make -s`:

```
default:
    @make -s build
    @make -s run
```

Better still:

```
default:
    @$(MAKE) -s build
    @$(MAKE) -s run
```

Even better:

```
default: run

build:
    @javac Test.java > /dev/null

run: build
    @java Test
```

Comment: Even even better. add .PHONY tags to the build and run targets.

Comment: Please, can you explain the 'Better still' solution? (what means `@$(MAKE)`?)

Comment: @Yukulélé: [the `MAKE` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#MAKE-Variable) contain the the name of the executable with which Make was invoked, and it gets some special treatment in a makefile recipe. The `@` [suppresses command echoing](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Echoing).

Comment: If run from the other working directory, eg. `make -C other/dir`, these solutions would still print the directory entering/leaving messages. Thanks for the tip in the 2nd one though!

Answer (score 64):

`make -s` suppresses other makefile messages also which might be important for developers. If you want to suppress "Entering/Leaving directory messages" only run `make` with

`make --no-print-directory`

Comment: >This only works with GNU Make.
[Tricks For Silencing Make](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Tricks-For-Silencing-Make.html).